# disable mouseover-ability on page load for 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked at some similar posts regarding interaction delay after page load, but I can't seem to find anything regarding the classical a:hover disable.

The problem is that JS will load most likely slower than the CSS, and hacking CSS isn't going to work for this problem.

**Situation**

I have a home page animation. On page load, i have a stack of images coming in from the left and a div of absolute anchor tags coming in from the right (~ 2 cases per line), which both slide and meet in the middle. After page load, I set a timer to go through the stack of images, and the corresponding anchor tag highlights.

The problem is that this timer is broken when the user hovers over any of the anchors tags, and when this happens, the corresponding image fades in. And this interaction could be right on page load.

Is there any possible way of disabling  **anchors tags a:hover** on page load/delay?

**What I've tried**

I cannot simply remove the a:hover class and replace it with another one of background-color:transparent, because my JS still picks up the onHover function (I could target onHover only for that changed class maybe..)

I am able to target each of the anchor tags on page load with an alert on mouseenter when accidentally hovering over:

```
//on page load, disable mouse-over ability on anchor tags
var disableOnLoad = function (ev) {
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var casesId = target.attr('id');

    //if mouse is over one of the cases
    if (target.is(".cases")) {
        //disable CSS a:hover
        $(this).removeClass('homeText a:hover');
    }
}
```

Another thing I might be able to try is calling **setTimeOut(function(){ onHover())** so that there is a delay, but that will effect after page load as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just have the hover functionality disabled by default then enable it after page load?

Comment: right or after your images are loaded as you stated you were monitoring that progress anyhow.

Comment: it's disabled until it's called on document.ready below the initial slide in of the images. The problem with this idea is that there still is a CSS class that can't be disabled, and so even though this idea won't stop my initial cycle animation, it will still look ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS:

```
 #blocker{
      position:fixed;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
      z-index:9999;
 }
```

JS:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
      $('#blocker').remove();
 }, 3000);
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
      <div id="blocker" ></div>
      <!-- your stuff -->
```

make sure the blocker div is close to the body tag to insure no capture/bubbling issues.

Comment: -.- this is such a simple idea, I'm glad you shared this with me.

Is there any draw backs to using a blocker on page load?

Comment: This what I would have suggested also. Go with this one.

Comment: You wouldn't see any content inside of that div until page had loaded PLUS 3 seconds, correct?

Comment: Assuming you mean the blocker div, there should never be any content in there. Its just to block the mouse from page content for 3 seconds, then the div is destroyed.

Comment: should I place the blocker *inside my div with the anchor tags? Or since it's fixed, on the outside?

Comment: OHHH!  I get it.  VERY clever  ;)

Comment: I'm wondering why i can still interact with the anchor tags... I haven't added the JS, so the div should be virtually blocking interaction right?

Comment: @BenSewards I updated my answer. Please do not put anything inside the blocker, leave it alone as a static element.

Comment: @Fresheyeball That's not the problem I'm having. The blocker covers the screen, but it's not stopping interaction. I put the JS in, and after 3 seconds the blocker does get removed.

Comment: oh ok. Are you sure the z-index is set so it is over the entire screen?

Comment: yes. Also, I set my anchor div z-index to -1, and that worked, but then after the block was removed, I still couldn't get any interaction. Then i tried setting it to 1, and the blocker, which has a z-index of 9999, isn't stopping interaction

Comment: you need to remove visibility:hidden from your blocker CSS, and then it will work. FIXED.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the discussion, but in case it helps anyone else, I solved my problem by adding `pointer-events: none` to the `body` element in CSS (using a class called `pointer-none`, and then removing it with JavaScript after a delay.

```
var timeout;
window.onload = function(){
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('pointer-none');
  }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if your page started out with your links as NOT wrapped with anchor tags, and you use a setTimeout onLoad to append the  tags 3 seconds later?

Comment: it's getting called on document.ready, which is the same context I believe.

would you know if it's possible to set a timeout on a separate page load that calls only the hover method?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you there.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested this but prevent default may work for you"

```
$("a").mouseover(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Run any other needed code here
});

(function(){
  $("a").unbind('mouseover');
}).delay(2000); // delay 2 seconds
```

Better to run the unbind code after you know all images are loaded

you may also want to modify the selector from all a tags to a.class